# How to fetch API and store some value and then fetch again with that stored value in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

Currently I am fetching some data and I save the response via `useState`. The response is saved but the problem is the second fetch takes place before the state was saved making that value `undefined`.

I tried to do like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrackingData().finally(() => {
      console.log("Destination", destination.coordinates);
      fetchDriverLocation().finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

Basically `fetchTrackingData` function has destination coordinates which I save with:

`const [destination, setDestination] = useState('');`

In the `fetchTrackingData` function I am setting the state after receiving the response. After `fetchTrackingData` is done fetching and it has saved state of `destination` I then use `finally()` method and then call the second fetch which is `fetchDriverLocation` but it has `destination` undefined and even I logged to see if the value gets saved after `finally()` but it is `undefined` in log as well.

How can I store the value from one API in that API call and then use that value in another API call?

Comment: Are you sure `fetchTrackingData` returns the data and sets the data as you expect?
Even if it does, `setDestination` will run asynchronously, so you can't be sure it ran before `fetchDriverLocation` is called. I think you're going to need to rethink how this logic is implemented. Unfortuantely, I'm not sure how exactly, but doing some searching here on stackoverflow will probably help out finding the correct pattern.

Comment: Yes it returns the data I can log that data and also sets the data because I am using one of the set values somewhere else and it shows up.

Comment: Then I think it's the asynchronous nature of `setDestination` . The destination isn't set immediately, causing the error (odd it's undefined, when you set default as `''`).  Can you show the code for `fetchTrackingData`?

Comment: It is happening because I am tapping into ```destination.coordinates``` but if I just console.log ```destination``` it doesn't show undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69444608/2089675) has stated, you are experiencing a race condition because `setState` in react is often [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

My suggestion would be to use two `useEffect`s to accomplish this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchTrackingData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Destination", destination.coordinates);
  fetchDriverLocation().finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, [destination]);
```

The above will wait until `destination` changes before moving on with fetching the driver location

Comment: This answer is also a good suggestion!

Comment: Thanks I was able to accomplish what I wanted via this method

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is a race condition.

When you call `fetchTrackingData`, it makes the HTTP request to your API, gets a response and then the last thing it does is saves `destination` to the `state`. But when you call `setDestination`, this is another asynchronous task that is kicked off, then you move directly to trying to access it from the state (which it may or may not be there, depending on how long it takes to set the state).

**My recommendation would be to either not rely on state for this process** (perhaps a variable will do? or even just passing along the result of your http request) or to lean more heavily on chaining these `Promises` and have the setting of the state be included in the `Promise` chain. However, I would favour the former suggestion

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

and: [Chain React setState callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229611/chain-react-setstate-callbacks)

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the `async` `await` methods and call the other APIs after the first one is done.

Example :

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [data2, setData2] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch("someURL");
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
      const responseList = await fetch("someURL" + json.data);
      const jsonData = await responseList.json();
      setData2(jsonData)
    })();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: using async/await is equivalent to what the OP has done. It won't solve the issue because setState is async

Answer (score -1):

by using useEffect fetching data **from firstURI** and sending **to secondURI**

```
  const [firstDate, setFirstData] = useState();
  const [secondDate, setSecondData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const firstResponse = await fetch("firstURI");
      const firstResponseData = await firstResponse.json();
      setFirstData(firstResponseData);
      
      const secondResponse = await fetch("secondURI" + firstResponseData.data);
      const secondResponseData = await secondResponse.json();
      setSecondData(secondResponseData)
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: This doesn't give a solution because it is equivalent to what the OP had done. The problem is with `setState` not waiting for a promise to resolve